# Assign action to variable in Automator for use in Shell Script

Tags: python, macos, shell, variables, automator

[image]

Ok, this thing is driving me crazy right now.  So Action 1 Chooses a Folder (I want to save that folder's path as var_1) and Action 3 Selects a File (I want to save this file's path as var_2)

so in the end . . .

```
var_1 = '/Users/Prometheus/Desktop/'
var_2 = '/Users/Prometheus/Documents/a.txt'
```

**So how do I use these variables and their values inside of Shell Script with python ?** I can't use sys.argv because they are set to some weird variables

I usually put 'Ask for Finder Item' > Run Shell Script and then

```
import sys

variable = open(argv[1]).read()
```

but i can't use that in this case . my scripts are in python so i'd rather stay in python because i don't know any other language

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Automator variables are only used in the Automator workflow. The variable themselves are not directly accessible to either a shell script or a Python script.  The `Run Shell Script` action allows you to pass the values of particular variables to a shell script in either of two ways: either piping them in through `stdin` or by passing them as execution arguments.  For this sort of use case, the latter is easier.  To start with, you need to pick Automator variable names in the `Set Value of Variable` and `Get Value of Variable` actions so the values selected can be retained between actions.  Here's a very rudimentary workflow example where I've selected two folders:

[image] [image]

Comment: you have no idea how much you just helped me out thank you so much . your explanation was very good it now makes sense what was happening before!

Answer (score 0):

You might use a Run AppleScript action like this to display the dialogs:

```
POSIX path of (choose folder default location (path to desktop))
result & linefeed & POSIX path of (choose file default location (path to desktop))
```

Then set "Pass input" to "to stdin" in the Run Shell Script action and use a script like this:

```
import sys
folder, file = sys.stdin.read().splitlines()
```